# Escaping question mark RewriteCond (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having issue making this redirection works. It seems like the issue come from the question mark `?page=` in the `RewriteCond`'s line. But can't find a way to escape the question mark.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/v/models/?page=([a-z\-A-Z0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . models.php?category=dog&page=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help?

Comment: The query string is _not_ part of `%{REQUEST_URI}`... You try to capture something that is not there... I suggest you start reading the documentation of the tools you use. As typical for OpenSource software the documentation of the apache http server's rewriting module is extremely precise and comes with lots of really useful examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/v/models/$ [NC]
RewriteRule . models.php?category=dog [L,QSA]
```

Adding QSA made it work (Query String Append)